# Convert JNI -> jobject (basically map and/or map of map in java file) to std::map(c++)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jnienv, jniwrapper

I have a native method in java file:-

```
class JNITest{
    public native void test(String param1, Map<String, Number> param2, Map<String, Map<String, Double>> param3)
}
```

After generating header file from java, map is converted to jobject in header file method:-

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_jni_JNITest_test
(JNIEnv *env,
jobject self,
jstring param1,
jobject param2,
jobject param3) { }
```

I have a native method in cpp as:

```
int cpp_native(
std::string param1,
std::map<std::string, float>& param2,
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, float> >& param3) { }
```

Q:- I need to convert Jobject back to std::map(cpp) to pass it to cpp native method, could anyone please suggest standard approach for doing the same?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try to access the std::map from Java using, for example, JavaCPP: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp  Let me know if you're interested, I could provide some example code as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

We have done a lot of work with C++/Java integration. The problem with passing complex data structures across the boundary is that you have to marshal the method invocations, which can be a really complex and error-prone endeavor.  I've found it much easier to do something like this:

- On the Java side, use gson or jackson to serialize your map to JSON
- Pass the JSON string across the boundary
- On the C++ side deserialize the JSON to a std::map

I'm not as familiar with the C++ side, but I see similar problems being addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046853/how-to-convert-a-json-object-to-a-map-with-nlohmannjson)

Answer (score 1):

It will require a little bit of struggle. Take a look here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-020/

also, take a look here for samples related to passing Map into native code

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo037
https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo038

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scapix::link::java](https://www.scapix.com/documentation/java_link) C++ JNI library to automatically convert between many C++ and Java types. Here is an [example](https://github.com/scapix-com/example2):

```cpp
#include <scapix/java_api/java/lang/System.h>
#include <scapix/java_api/java/util/Locale.h>
#include <scapix/java_api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.h>

using namespace scapix::link::java;
using namespace scapix::java_api;

void test1()
{
    // C++ objects are automatically converted to and from corresponding Java types.
    // This works for any type supported by scapix::link::java::convert() interface,
    // which supports many STL types and can be extended for your own types.

    std::string version = java::lang::System::getProperty("java.version");
    std::vector<std::string> languages = java::util::Locale::getISOLanguages();
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> zone_strings = java::text::DateFormatSymbols::getInstance()->getZoneStrings();
    std::map<std::string, std::string> properties = java::lang::System::getProperties();
}
```